# Can´t retrieve the date from MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

I do an INSERT into mySQL database like this:

```
$sDate=date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
INSERT INTO tbl_1 (datum) VALUES ('$sDate')
```

And it'll do the INSERT
But then when I try to find out the unique ID by selecting the date like this:

```
SELECT id AS nyPost FROM tbl_1 WHERE datum ='$sDate'
```

It will return nothing, not even an error message. The datum format is datetime.
Please whats wrong?
CODE:

```
    <?php
        $sDate=date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
        echo $sDate;
    If ($strNy) 
    {
        $_nyPrSQL="INSERT INTO begagnads (`anvId`, `tabort`, `datum`) VALUES ('8' , 'null', '$sDate')";

    //  echo  $_nyPrSQL;
        if (!mysqli_query($con,$_nyPrSQL)) 
        {die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));}
        else
        {
        echo "<br>1 record added";
        }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id FROM begagnads WHERE DATE(datum) ='$sDate' ");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['id'] . " " . $row['datum'];
  $nyPost= $row['id'];
  echo "<br>";
}
    ?>
```

Comment: you have inserted  `CURRENT date` in table and when you run `SELECT` query current date will be increased??

Comment: Yes CURRENT date will be increased but Im not interested in that. I want to find the same ROW that I inserted the date to. The date will be saved in the variable $sDate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySql  [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function Extracts the date part of the date or datetime expression expr.

```
mysql> SELECT DATE('2003-12-31 01:02:03');
        -> '2003-12-31'
```

If you want to find by `DATE` only

```
SELECT id FROM begagnads WHERE DATE(datum) = DATE('$sDate')
```

And if you find with date and time then no need `DATE()` function

```
SELECT id FROM begagnads WHERE datum = '$sDate'
```

Comment: Its working now and I haven't changed anything. Strange!
`SELECT id, datum FROM begagnads WHERE datum ='$sDate'`
Another small problem is how to format the date so the hours are in 24 hours format, before inserting?
Never mind , I found it out `$sDate=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");`

Comment: date type variable only support `YYYY-MM-DD H:i:s` format, you can change date format into `SELECT` query from `DATE_FORMAT()` function

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_1 (datum) VALUES ($sDate)
```

Try looking at your table named `tbl_1` after the above, by using:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_1
```

Comment: without `(')` small quote insert query gives error?

Comment: What error? You're probably trying to insert something that doesn't fit into the `datum` field. What type is this field?

Comment: I get the error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '02:43:28)' at line 1` and thats where the space is between date and time. The type of the field is datetime.

Comment: @mzedeler in the query `int` and `float` type values can only use without quote.

Comment: Sure. You are right. The problem isn't related to SQL alone. You'd be much better off if you post your code (I assume it is PHP).

Comment: Thats right, I am formatting the date into string first and then inserting it into table and it IS there I can see it by phpMaAdmin.

Comment: Your descriptions says `SELECT id FROM begagnads WHERE datum ='$sDate'`, but the code says `SELECT id FROM begagnads WHERE DATE(datum) ='$sDate'`, which is not going to work.

Comment: @mzedeler I was trying some tricks which didnt help.
`WHERE datum ='$sDate'` isnt working either.